# Integrate Multi-Dimensional Gaussian to Marginalize Dimension

Tags: integration, gaussian-integral, marginal-distribution

I would like to understand how to integrate out one of the dimensions of a multi-dimensional Gaussian. Here is a simple setting:

x ~ N($\mu_x$,$\sigma_x^2$)
y ~ N($\mu_y$,$\sigma_y^2$)

We form a new random variable through linear addition: z = ax +by

Then z ~ N($a\mu_x + b\mu_y$,$a^2\sigma_x^2 + b^2\sigma_y^2$)

Now suppose I want to get back the marginal pdf of x. Then:
$f_x(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x,y)dy$.

More explicitly,
$f_x(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(a^2\sigma_x^2 + b^2\sigma_y^2)}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{\frac{(ax+by-a\mu_x + b\mu_y)^2}{2(a^2\sigma_x^2 + b^2\sigma_y^2)}}dy$.

One option is to expand the exponent. Some terms come out of the integral, but the remaining terms contain a number of cross terms remaining. Specifically: 2abxy -2abx$\mu_x$ - 2aby$\mu_y$ +2ab$\mu_x\mu_y$.

How is this normally handled?

Comment: What was the point of introducing z?

Comment: Strictly speaking, there is no point. It just in most of the derivations on the joint density and I added it by inertia. Do you know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you have a multidimensional gaussian rv $X=(x_1,\dots, x_n)$, and you would like to find the distribution of $(x_2,\dots, x_n)$. In general, if $X$ is multidimensional gaussian with mean $\mu$ and covariance $C$, and $A: \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ is any linear map, then $AX$ is also multidimensional gaussian with mean $A\mu$ and covariance $A CA^T$ (this can be seen most easily using the formula for the characteristic function of a gaussian). In your case, the matrix $C$ is diagonal with entries $\sigma_x^2,\sigma_y^2$ and $A$ is the matrix of the projection onto the first coordinate $A=(1,0)$, thus recovering the distribution of X

Comment: Thanks Mike. This is a good understanding of the question. However, I would like to know exactly how to do the integral. I would like to do this in the simple case where n = 1 and m = 2.